# Why looping on the list using one of its elements makes gives that output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, iteration

How does having a[-1] as a counter changes its value and if it happens to change; why in the last iteration it doesn't (In the 3rd line of the output it got the value of 2 but the next iteration it didn't change!!!)

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for a[-1] in a:
    print(a[-1], '_' * 5, a)
```

The output:

```
0 _____ [0, 1, 2, 0]
1 _____ [0, 1, 2, 1]
2 _____ [0, 1, 2, 2]
2 _____ [0, 1, 2, 2]
```

The expected output:

```
3 _____ [0, 1, 2, 3]
3 _____ [0, 1, 2, 3]
3 _____ [0, 1, 2, 3]
3 _____ [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: How could there possibly be a 3 in the output?  You overwrite the only element of the list holding a 3 on the very first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Out of all possibilities (and there's a whole lot of them), why would one chose *a[-1]* as an iteration variable?